# A deck of $52$ cards is divided into $13$ piles of $4$ cards each.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have the following question in a Discrete Mathematics course I am taking. We are currently studying Intro to Graph Theory.

A standard deck of $52$ cards (no Jokers) is divided into $13$ pile of $4$ cards. Prove that by choosing one card from each pile you can choose all of the numbers ($2$-$10$, Ace, K, Q, J).

I thought of making a graph $G=(V,E)$ such that $V$ is the group of all cards and that $\forall u,v
\in V\colon \{a,b\}\in E \iff a\text{ and }b \text{ have the same number or are in the same pile.}$

I can show that if you a connected component exists that has only $4$ vertices than they are all of the same number, and we can just pick a card from that pile of cards, no matter which. It is also pretty simple to show that a connected component of more than one pile, containing $4k$ for $1<k\le 13$, it must contain $k$ cards with different numbers.

I am struggling to show that for a connected component containing more than one pile, you can choose all different of $k$ cards with different numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you could not pick all thirteen numbers from the thirteen piles, then there would have to be a pile which contains all the aces, say, and also all the twos, so that you could not pick both a two and an ace. That isn't possible since there are only four cards in each pile. There isn't any possible arrangement of cards where there are **not** thirteen different numbers in the thirteen piles.